# is there any winapi call to check if drive has assigned a valid recycle bin?

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application, recycle-bin

I mean the situation with removable drives or other non typical HDD's that do not have recycle bin (even if there is a such directory in main path, maybe the drive was connected before as non-removable, who knows) and all files are permanently deleted from such drive, even if using [SHFileOperation/SHFILEOPSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I've tried this call: [SHQueryRecycleBin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - but this is only for desktop apps, and so returns zero on all it's data outputs no matter if I give it a fixed C drive or removable flash.

I found also this approach: [How can I tell that a directory is really a recycle bin?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/18/8956382.aspx) , but here I must know first for what directory to look, and I do not want to get to such details, I want to know only if given file will be destroyed or moved to recycle bin.

A side question: is it possible to force system to move a file to recycle bin from a flash drive that doesn't have it ? The only way I think it is approachable is to move the file to the system temp dir and then delete it from there ?

Comment: You say "this is only for desktop apps" - what type of app are you writing?

Comment: A console one, it's in the tags.

Comment: You should be able to use that function from a console app too. When MSDN says "desktop apps only" they mean "not Metro/Modern/Whatever".

Comment: So can anyone show me a snipped where this is working, I've tried to coin from scraps I found on the web but damn thing returs zero from every orifice.

Comment: I tested it in a console app and it's fine, it doesn't really tell you if a drive has a recycle bin though, it succeeds on drives that do not and the number of items and size are 0, just like on a drive with an empty recycle bin.

Comment: Note that there can be directories which use the recycle bin even though the drive doesn't have one.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Interesting concept. I've understood that "Recycle Bin" was nothing more than a subdirectory on each drive to which you can move files (really just moving the directory entry). But if the directory has a recycle bin that's not on the same drive, moving a file to the recycle bin must be implemented as a copy&delete. That's not fast. What causes such directories?

Comment: Well, that changes the problem. Now the question is how for individual file to check if it will be moved to recycle or permanently before the action ?

Comment: @MSalters Those special recycle bins are on the same drive but not in the root. They are used in corporate deployment scenarios.